# Update each row of PostgreSQL table using shell script

Tags: database, postgresql, shell

I have a shell script which has a list of ips.

Under the for loop of that script, every time 15 ips are picked and changed the status to 'removed'.

Can some expert shed some light on how should I update those list of ips under a shell script's for loop?
Meaning what should I do from inside the for loop of shell script to make those continuous changes to PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 3):

You can make changes to a PostgreSQL database using the command line tool `psql`. If you have a password needed for the updated you can set the PGPASSWORD environment variable. Example:

```
PGPASSWORD="mypassword" psql -U username -c database "statement"
```

If no password is needed, do

```
psql -U username -c database "statement"
```

and if no username is needed for the access, you can do

```
psql -c database "statement"
```

For the random IPs to change, I would either create an array of all IPs using `psql` with a

```
SELECT * FROM ips;
```

and then create 15 random numbers, use these as index (of course you have to make sure no random number is created twice) and then set them to status removed in the database.

After reading the comments:
To update you could do:

```
updateIP=`echo ip_string | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
psql -U user -c database "UPDATE iptable SET status='status_removed' WHERE ip='${updateIP}';"
```

To update a single record, given you store the IP in the table "iptable" enter the column "ip" and the status under column "status".

Comment: Thanks Nidhoegger, let me try that on my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
psql -U pgsql -d database -c "statement"
```

For FreeBSD based systems at least, the above statement would work. The flags are different in postgres 10. Likely the same would be true for linux as well.